# Segment image into high and low frequencies

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an image that's composed of high and low frequency information (see attached), and I'd like to set the values of high frequency pixels to 0 whilst maintaining the pixels value of low frequency information.

For example in the image below, the pixels for the skin would remain the same, but detail on the hat would be set to 0.

I am aware that I can use a low or high pass filter by converting the image to frequencies and back with a Fourier transform, but I am not looking to remove frequencies. Instead I'd like to alter the pixel values were high frequencies occur. I've heard that this may be possible using a biorthogonal wavelet transform, but I'm unfamiliar with how to implement this in Python.

By the way, my goal is to implement the technique [described in this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/310744486_Cloud_Extraction_from_Chinese_High_Resolution_Satellite_Imagery_by_Probabilistic_Latent_Semantic_Analysis_and_Object-Based_Machine_Learning) (see 3.2.1 (c) and "Frequency Feature").

[Lena](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPFk2.png)
My progress so far is summarised in this code:

```
import pywt
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread

image = imread('lena.png')

coeffs = pywt.wavedec2(image, 'bior3.5', level=2)

plt.imshow(abs(np.mean(coeffs[1], axis=0)))
```

My assumption is that a 2-level decomposition should leave me with high and low frequencies, it looks like the arrays within the 1st layer `coeffs[1]` represent different angles of high frequency. This led me to combine them all via averaging and plot them to produce a map of all high frequency areas in the image.

[High frequency Lena](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kzHl.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62327464/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can use PyWavelets

Comment: @BelalHomaidan thank you for your feedback, I've updated my question to include some of the code I've used; I was initially reserved to do this since my "solution" is most likely misguided

Comment: @BarneyGordon *I am aware that I can use a low or high pass filter by converting the image to frequencies and back with a Fourier transform, but I am not looking to remove frequencies.* use Fourier transform, and low pass filter, then subtract the result from the original to have high frequencies, so you will have Low, and High frequencies seperated.